Distinguish Angular Component instance from other types
In Angular, how can I distinguish a Component (from @angular/core) instance from ... anything else?
My function expects either an Angular Component instance or an HTML Element. I've tried checking for instanceof Component, but that won't work, since it's decorated instead of extending Component.
EDIT
Checking for instanceof Type won't work for me, since my subject will (or won't) be an instance of a @Component-decorated class, rather than the associated class itself.

Ideally, I'd expect some framework-provided check, but I couldn't find one. What's the canonical way to check this (at run-time)? The following work-around is very kludgy:
function isComponent(subject: Component | HTMLElement) {
  // return subject instanceof Component; // always false
  // return subject as unknown instanceof Type; // only works when subject is an Angular-decorated class
  return !!(subject.constructor as any).ɵcmp; // works, but uses Angular-internals and anyScript
}


this is the only way afaik. you chould make your isComponent a type guard function to improve typings in branching code function isComponent(subject: Component | HTMLElement): subject is Component {

subject.constructor.hasOwnProperty('ɵcmp')
